# Change Custom Mouse Cursor when using the Konami Code

Tags: mouse-cursor

I would like to know how to implement an easter egg on my website. I would like it so that whenever someone uses the Konami Code, they get a custom mouse. I have the image that I would like to use, but I would like to know how to implement it on my site. (If you want to check my website out, you can [here](http://www.homeofthelords.com))

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple implementation of your problem in pure javascript, which you should be able to bake into your website. Basically, I capture keyboard events and if you enter the code correctly the css class that controls the cursor's appearance is changed. I included a generic cursor file (fish.cur) I found on the internet, but you will have to make your own to customize it. There is probably a better solution, but this is pretty simple, platform agnostic and works.

Here is a demo:
http://whereshappening.com/EasterEggs/CustomCursor/

And here is the source code:
https://github.com/joshpierro/EasterEgg/tree/master/CustomCursor

Answer (score 0):

js

```
var kkeys = [], konami = "38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65";
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
      kkeys.push( e.keyCode );
      if ( kkeys.toString().indexOf( konami ) >= 0 ){
        $(document).unbind('keydown',arguments.callee);
        // Launch easter egg here          
         };
```

not sure how relevant it is now but this is what I used to listen for the kode, then just toggling classes inside it.